# Css issue div height when using float

Tags: css, css-float

I have a `div` area like this:

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.con{
    width:100%;     
}
.con .container{
    width:70%;
    min-height:500px;
    float:left;
    background:#f00;

}
.con .sidebar{
    width:30%;
    min-height:500px;
    float:right;
    background:#ccc;

}
```

The `container` and `sidebar` class heights are dynamic. When one of these class heights increases, class `con` also has to increase. But my problem is class `con` height is always 0, I can't seem to give the `con` class a static height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `.con`:

```
.con {
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use clear class

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.clear
{
   clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it matters why `.con` does not extend in height, but this is a pretty infamous problem.  Add `overflow: hidden` to `.con`.  If that does not work, put `<br style="clear: both;">` after the tag.

Comment: its because of float if we set float to child element and not the parent .. it happen .. overflow hidden is not thing to do however it can be done by `clear:both`  or float

Comment: @NullPointer the `overflow: hidden` trick works practically every time unless it actually ends up cutting off content

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.con{
    width:auto; 
    overflow: auto;
    margin:0 auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like..

```
.con{display: table;}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding an explanation why this will work or even an actual code sample showing your suggestion.